# simple way to create /a /b patch?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, diff, patch, openwrt

Some strange things like OpenWRT want patches in format:

```
diff -urN a/src/util.c b/src/util.c
--- a/src/util.c        2017-04-21 23:22:06.895516111 +0300
+++ b/src/util.c        2017-04-21 23:22:19.595595344 +0300
```

Now to create such a patch I have to do next actions:

```
mkdir -p a/src
mkdir -p b/src
cd src/
cp util.c ../a/src/
cp util.c.orig ../b/src/util.c
cd ..
diff -urN a/ b/ > 001-watchdog.patch
```

Is there a way to avoid so?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest would be to use `git diff`